# Angular 6 show or hide list items

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have simple angular app which displays list items,  I want when first list item is clicked list description(card) is displayed , when second list  item is clicked and description is displayed the first list description(card) should be hidden ,

Here is stackblitz for reference: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar-cidoez?file=src/app/app.component.html

html:

```
<div class="why-choose-us__description">
      <ul class="why-choose-us__list-top">
        <li class="why-choose-us__leader" 
        (click)="toggleCard()"
        style="background-image: url('/assets/images/solidne-fundamenty.png')">
          <h4>Inspiring Leaders1</h4>
          <div class="why-choose-us__card card" *ngIf="showCard">
            <p>Thanks to belonging to an international organization, which operates since 1988 and has a huge knowledge base,
              ASTEK Poland enjoys its stable position on the market.</p>
            <div class="close-icon"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
          <li class="why-choose-us__leader" 
        (click)="toggleCard()"
        style="background-image: url('/assets/images/solidne-fundamenty.png')">
          <h4>Inspiring Leaders2</h4>
          <div class="why-choose-us__card card" *ngIf="showCard">
            <p>Thanks to belonging to an international organization, which operates since 1988 and has a huge knowledge base,
              ASTEK Poland enjoys its stable position on the market.</p>
            <div class="close-icon"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
          <li class="why-choose-us__leader" 
        (click)="toggleCard()"
        style="background-image: url('/assets/images/solidne-fundamenty.png')">
          <h4>Inspiring Leaders3</h4>
          <div class="why-choose-us__card card" *ngIf="showCard">
            <p>Thanks to belonging to an international organization, which operates since 1988 and has a huge knowledge base,
              ASTEK Poland enjoys its stable position on the market.</p>
            <div class="close-icon"></div>
          </div>
        </li>


      </ul>
 </div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
    showCard = false;

  toggleCard() {
    this.showCard = !this.showCard;
  }
}
```

Now when I click one of my list all card descriptions from other list also is displayed .

what am I missing in my codes? any help will be apreciated, thanks

Comment: It is because you are using the same boolean value in the ngIf on all of them. If you set up individual booleans for each ngIf and pass something to toggleCard to say which one is being pressed, then you can easily toggle each one and hide the others on toggle.

Comment: @CodeMonkey am new to this stuff , how can I do that using switch? or please provide some similra tutorial if you can

Comment: You can use Augustin R's answer. That is close to what you want.

Comment: Yes, Its exactly what I want ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I will prefer to use an array of leaders, with a boolean field:

```js
inspiringLeaders = [
    {
      name: 'Inspiring leaders 1',
      text: 'Thanks to belonging to an international organization, which operates since 1988 and has a huge knowledge base, ASTEK Poland enjoys its stable position on the market.',
      shown: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Inspiring leaders 2',
      text: 'Thanks to belonging to an international organization, which operates since 1988 and has a huge knowledge base, ASTEK Poland enjoys its stable position on the market.',
      shown: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Inspiring leaders 3',
      text: 'Thanks to belonging to an international organization, which operates since 1988 and has a huge knowledge base, ASTEK Poland enjoys its stable position on the market.',
      shown: false
    }
  ];

toggleCard(leader: { name: string, text: string, shown: boolean }) {
    this.inspiringLeaders.map((l) => {
      if (l.name === leader.name) {
        l.shown = !l.shown;
      } else {
        l.shown = false;
      }
    });
}
```

and use a `ngFor` loop in the .html :

```html
<div class="why-choose-us__description">
    <ul class="why-choose-us__list-top">
        <li class="why-choose-us__leader" (click)="toggleCard(leader)" style="background-image: url('/assets/images/solidne-fundamenty.png')"
         *ngFor="let leader of inspiringLeaders">
            <h4>{{leader.name}}</h4>
            <div class="why-choose-us__card card" *ngIf="leader.shown">
                <p>{{leader.text}}</p>
                <div class="close-icon"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar-apffb1?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

**EDIT**
Show only one text at a time.

Comment: Excactly what I wanted , Thanks alot